# Request to https://httpbin.org/post has broken (status 413)

Tags: reactjs, dropzone

I use react-dropzone-uploader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone-uploader). 
It allow upload images through dropzone.
This solution was great.

Usually, when I choose images, it upload files to `https://httpbin.org/post` (for validation (?)).
But now whichever image I choose (even those that were successfully uploaded earlier), this request fails with status 413 (Request Entity Too Large Error). My images aren't large.
This error occurs both in my locale solution and in the examples from quick start tutorial.

You can see error on https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/quick-start. Just try to upload some images and see Network in DevTools.

Comment: Trying exactly what you described, I get a 200, and cannot reproduce. Apart from that it's probably a better idea to create an issue in the github repo if you made sure your images are in fact not too big.

Comment: I have already created an issue in the github repo, but nobody answered to me.
Also I have written to support of PixelStrap (this is team, they have solution for sites that includes react-dropzone-uploader library) and they fixed it. It's OK now :)